# How to modify ReadSensor.ino from AllSensors_DLHR Library to utilize different sensors

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c

This question is regarding the [AllSensors_DLHR](https://github.com/jeremycole/AllSensors_DLHR) library. I am trying to specifically interface with the All Sensors DLHR-L60D pressure sensor. Compiling the unmodified [ReadSensor.ino](https://github.com/jeremycole/AllSensors_DLHR/blob/master/examples/ReadSensor/ReadSensor.ino) produces no serial output; however, it is set-up for a different sensor. I edited it to the following:

```
#include <AllSensors_DLHR.h>

AllSensors_DLHR_L60D_8 differentialPressure(&Wire);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Wire.begin();

  differentialPressure.setPressureUnit(AllSensors_DLHR::PressureUnit::PASCAL);
}

void loop() {
  differentialPressure.startMeasurement();
  differentialPressure.readData(true);
  Serial.print("Pressure: ");
  Serial.print(differentialPressure.pressure);
  Serial.print(" Temperature: ");
  Serial.println(differentialPressure.temperature);

  delay(100);
}
```

This sketch compiles, but still doesn't produce output. I have inserted a `Serial.println("hello");` below line `differentialPressure.startMeasurement();` which prints, but when I insert it below line `differentialPressure.readData(true);` it doesn't print; presumably getting hung up here as nothing further is printed to the serial monitor.

I've cycled through the AllSensors_DLHR_L60D_8, AllSensors_DLHR_L60D_7, and AllSensors_DLHR_L60D_6, none of which work for me.

Additionally, I've used an i2c scanner to verify the sensor's address as (0x29), which is the same as the  [library's header file](https://github.com/jeremycole/AllSensors_DLHR/blob/master/src/AllSensors_DLHR.h).

Not sure what else to do at this point. My end goal is to use this library with my sensor. Any help/comments/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: My comment would not solve the problem. But, I can at least explain what is happening. For some reason, the busy bit in the status byte is high. See line 64 ~ 83 of AllSensors_DLHR.cpp. It keeps looping until the busy bit goes low.